# mp3 encoding at different bitrates using ffmpy into python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, mp3, bitrate

I am trying to convert a .flac audio file into an .mp3 at different bitrates. The simple code is the following:

```
import ffmpy
ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(inputs={'in.flac': None},outputs={'out.mp3': None})
ff.run()
```

Now, since I want my out.mp3, let's say, at 320k, I modify the second line of the code as follows:

```
ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(inputs={'in.flac': None},outputs={'out.mp3': '-ab 320k'})
```

The problem is that I am not sure I am using the right command in the right position, by inserting

```
'-ab 320k'
```

or

```
'-ab 320000'
```

The script seems to run correctly and Python does the conversion into mp3 but the bitrate is always 128 (I am checking it by using eyed3). 
How can I modify my code to get 320kbps?

Comment: Confirm that it's not a bug of eyed3 by dividing the size of the generated MP3 by its duration.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug. I've tried to encode various .flac into .mp3 with audacity and the eyed3 command gives me the correct bitrates.

Comment: Maybe, but eyed3 may not be parsing the ffmpeg MP3 correctly. Just eliminate that possibility first.

Comment: I am using this specific function

`f = mp3.Mp3AudioFile('path/filename.mp3')
bitrate = f.info.bit_rate
print(bitrate)`

how can I be sure if it's working or not?

Comment: Download one of the MP3s locally and divide its filesize by the duration.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(
 inputs={'16 Bit Lolitas - Beat Organ (Original Mix).mp4': None},
 outputs={'16 Bit Lolitas - Beat Organ (Original Mix).mp3': ['-ab', '320k']}
)
```